# pyspark function to change datatype

Tags: pyspark

The code is working outside the function however when I take it inside the function and adjust for var argument passed, I am getting an error. Thanks for the help!

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unix_timestamp, to_date

def change_string_to_date(df,var):       
     df = df.withColumn("{}".format(var),to_date(unix_timestamp(col("{}".format(var))), 'yyyy-MM-dd').cast("timestamp"))    
     return df

df_data = change_string_to_date(df_data,'mis_dt')
```

Comment: And what errors are you getting?

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4544.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`"mis_dt"`' given input columns: [id, a.mis_dt, rec];;
'Project [id#25919, mis_dt#25942, rec#25920, cast(to_date(unix_timestamp('"mis_dt", yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, None), Some(yyyy-MM-dd)) as timestamp) AS "mis_dt"#25960]

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. "unix_timestamp" was causing the problem . very silly error.